# interactive elements not receiving focus with tab, even when using tabindex="0"

Tags: javascript, html, input, keyboard-events

I built an app that takes input inside and outside a table. I noticed that using the tab key is not cycling through all of the interactive elements. If I place my cursor in the very first input field, I can tab all the way through to the first row of the table (which contains three inputs and a button), however, when I get to the second input field and hit tab, the focus returns to the first input of the table row, instead of moving on to the third input. If I click to focus on the third input in the table, tab once will go back out to the table (it seems to be focusing on the tbody?), then tab again returns to the first input in the table row. Shift+tab backs out of the table, as expected. I tried adding `tabindex="0"` with no change.

HTML generated using JavaScript, code in question beginning on line 131: https://github.com/ykbell09/yarnCalculator/blob/master/index.js

```js
            // add cost per
            const costPer = newRow.insertCell();
            const costPerInput = document.createElement('input');
            costPerInput.className = 'input-table num';
            costPerInput.value = yarn.costPer;
            costPer.appendChild(costPerInput);
            costPerInput.addEventListener('blur', () => {
                yarn.costPer = costPerInput.value;
                saveData();
                displayData();
            });
```

Application:
https://distracted-wing-c0b75c.netlify.app/

Any thoughts on why I can't tab through all the inputs?

Comment: Please post relevant code here as text, not as a link or image :)

Comment: One thing to note, from the code posted here: It's `tabindex`, not `tabinput`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems not to be a tab index issue, so much as a code issue. I've tracked it down to this code:

```
// update new pattern yardage data and calculations
patternYardsInput.addEventListener('blur', () => {
    pattern.yards = patternYardsInput.value;
    saveData();
    displayData();
});
```

After you tab off of that input, which means it's losing focus (blur), you're calling the method `displayData` which is rewriting that HTML. Since where you were focused no longer exists in the DOM, it's throwing off where you were focused with the tab key.

Answer (score 1):

when the tab cycle enter the table area , it start to loop elements on the table,
simply just add tabindex property to Your Table like This: tabindex=-1

for example:

```
<table tabindex=-1 >
```